# How to get the index of the Promise returned by Promise.any from an array of Promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to implement a queue of promises that fetch images. So, I create an array of 3 promises and get the first fetched image using `Promise.any()`. But when I receive the first image, I want to replace the used promise with a new one. Example:

```js
const images = [
    fetch("some/image"),
    fetch("another/image"),
    fetch("another/image"),
];

Promise.any(images).then(img => {
    images[n] = fetch("another/image") // if only I knew "n"
    return img
}).then(/*whatever*/)
```

I've tried finding the index by comparing each promise of the array to the one returned by `Promise.any`, but that didn't work since it returns a new promise.

So, how do I know the index of the promise who's value was returned by `Promise.any`'s promise?

Comment: why replace it? the `Promise.any` won't be called again

Comment: what's the end goal here? theres likely a better way to do this

Comment: The `Promise.any` will be called repeatedly in an iterator of images. I'm trying to create an iterator of images that prefetches them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add index for each image promise before passing them to `Promise.any` (add `.then` chain)

```js
const images = [
    Promise.resolve("some/image1"),
    Promise.resolve("some/image2"),
    Promise.resolve("some/image3"),
];

Promise.any(images.map((p, i) => p.then(v => [v, i]))).then(([img, index]) => {
    console.log('image', img)
    console.log('index', index)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [promise-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-limit) package for this purpose. It allows you to solve your problem in a more robust way:

```
var promiseLimit = require('promise-limit')
 
var limit = promiseLimit(2) // max count of simultaneous requests
 
var allImages = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
 
Promise.all(allImages.map((name) => {
  return limit(() => fetch(name).then(imageLoadedCallback))
}))
```

Comment: Thanks! Sound like a good optimization to do

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typescript function I'm using based on @KiraLT's answer.

```
async function promiseAnyIndexed<T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(
  values: T
): Promise<(Awaited<T[number]> | undefined)[]> {
  const response = await Promise.any(values.map((promise, index) => promise.then((result) => ({ result, index }))))
  const result = new Array(values.length)
  result[response.index] = response.result
  return result
}
```